# Cannot transition entry that is not in the back stack, but currentBackStack.value shows that it is

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation-graph

I'm trying to programmatically go back to the `Fragment` that called another `Fragment`. Inside the called `Fragment`, I used `findNavController().popBackStack()` to try to got back to the previous `Fragment` in the backstack, but I'm getting the error I mentioned in the title. Then I called `findNavController().currentBackStack.value` to see what the backstack looks like, and it looks complete. The called `Fragment`, the caller `Fragment` and all the previous `Fragment` that was shown was in the `currentBackStack.value`. So, if `currentBackStack.value` has the complete backstack, then why am I getting an error? I can for sure just add another action for going back to the previous `Fragment`, but using `findNavController().popBackStack()` is surely an easier way in the long run

UPDATE:
So I created a another action from the called `Fragment` to the caller `Fragment`, and it seems that it might not a workaround I could use in my situation. The caller `Fragment` has an object argument that it receives from another more previous `Fragment`, and I didn't know that if I made a return action to it, I would need to give the caller `Fragment` that object again, which the called `Fragment` doesn't really have a way to easily get access/reference to. Btw, the ActionBar back button works fine, and already hooked to the navigation.

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

Comment: Please add stacktrace for better resolution.